# Why does inheritAttrs even exist in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In Vue, we have the `inheritAttrs` component option which, when `false`, will prevent bindings from being applied as attributes to the DOM when not declared as `props` on the component instance.

For example, consider this:

```
<some-component :article="article" />
```

With `inheritAttrs` set to `true` (default):

```
<div article="[object Object]"></div>
```

With `inheritAttrs` set to `false`:

```
<div></div>
```

I am trying to understand a) why this is `true` by default? and b) why it even exists in the first place?

Allowing custom attributes in the DOM encourages less experienced engineers to produce invalid HTML, and as a result, poor quality code. However, I am inclined to trust the experience of the Vue engineers and therefore come to the conclusion that it is, in fact, useful in certain scenarios that I have not yet come across. If there are use cases where this is okay then I would like to know, and if there aren't, why on earth is it there in the first place?

In addition, is there a way to set this globally? I tried the following (didn't work):

```
Vue.config.inheritAttrs = false;
```

Comment: Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61253405/why-does-inheritattrs-even-exist-in-vue#comment108367331_61256252), it sounds like you'd like to bind multiple props at once without explicitly binding them by name. This can be [accomplished](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object) with `<child v-bind="myPropsObj" />`, where `myPropsObj` contains one or more props expected by child (unknown props are ignored by the child).

Comment: @tony19 - thanks Tony, however this isn't actually what I was looking for. I am aware of that sort of solution. What I was actually looking for was a deeper explanation of what `inheritAttrs` does as from what I could see, it simply prevented the generation of invalid HTML. However, I do now understand the purpose of it and actually, the functionality makes sense the way it is implemented. I originally thought I had come across something that shouldn't have been there in the first place, and that's why I wanted clarification on what it was actually meant for :-D

Comment: I agree that it would be easier and more explicit to manage it manually using `v-bind="$attrs"` anywhere required. Maybe it is handled differently in Vue3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with custom HTML attributes. You can to this regardless of `inheritAttrs` or not.

It is a valuable mechanism when you're writing components that wrap existing HTML elements. Without this, you would need to bind each attribute one by one in your top element.

It is more of a convenience than a necessary features.

Comment: Hi Radu, thank you for your answer. However, can you elaborate a little further? Are you refering to passing parent props to a child without explicitly binding them onto the child? If so, that is a good point and I agree it has a use case (in fact that is something I would love to use immediately). My problem is that when they are not declared as props on the child, they then get defined as custom attributes on the DOM element unless I specify `inheritAttrs: false`. Thinking about this further, this is beginning to make sense... I just hate the idea of custom attributes being added to the DOM

Comment: In the example I posted, if the child just references `article` like so; `$attrs.article` then there is no need to define it as a prop and therefore I have to explicitly define `inheritAttrs: false` in order to prevent `article="[Object object]"` being inserted into the DOM

Comment: It only works for attributes that are not props. I think not working for props is actually a very good idea. If you have data with the same name it would not be clear which ones to be applied, the inherited ones or the explicitly declared ones.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, that by accident you're creating unwanted HTML attributes, but I think this is a decision that should be left on the programmers shoulders. The component is not rendered in the DOM, so if I add HTML attributes to it it makes sense for them to be moved in the template. It is the programmers responsibility if those are valid or not

Comment: Ah, so are you saying that I can completely remove `:article="article"`, then remove `inheritAttrs: false` and I will still be able to access `$attrs.article` becuase it is inherited?

Comment: Will it only be inherited if it is defined as a `prop` on the parent? As in `data` won't be inherited from the parent obviously...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global mixin to disable this option for all components by default:

```
Vue.mixin({ inheritAttrs: false })
```

If you needed to inherit attributes for a particular component, explicity adding `inheritAttrs: true` would override the global mixin configuration.